# Nested directory creator: Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, directory

How can I create a nested directory in Phonegap with this API?

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Android/data/com.phonegap.myapp/dir_one/dir_two/", {create:true}, gotDir, onError);
```

I am using Phonegap 1.8.0 in Android 2.2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This function will help you create nested dirs.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("device is ready");
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function fail() {
    console.log("failed to get filesystem");
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    window.FS = fileSystem;

    var printDirPath = function(entry){
        console.log("Dir path - " + entry.fullPath);
    }

    createDirectory("dhaval/android/apps", printDirPath);
    createDirectory("this/is/nested/dir", printDirPath);
    createDirectory("simple_dir", printDirPath);
}

function createDirectory(path, success){
    var dirs = path.split("/").reverse();
    var root = window.FS.root;

    var createDir = function(dir){
        console.log("create dir " + dir);
        root.getDirectory(dir, {
            create : true,
            exclusive : false
        }, successCB, failCB);
    };

    var successCB = function(entry){
        console.log("dir created " + entry.fullPath);
        root = entry;
        if(dirs.length > 0){
            createDir(dirs.pop());
        }else{
            console.log("all dir created");
            success(entry);
        }
    };

    var failCB = function(){
        console.log("failed to create dir " + dir);
    };

    createDir(dirs.pop());
}
```

For full example check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2901135)

Comment: very good example for understanding basic as well as at advance level. thanks dhavan

Answer (score 2):

Just to add something to dhaval's function: it's not bullet proof for any browser compliant with Javascript Filesystem. If you use it with Chrome and your path is an empty string, it will fail, because apparently, with Chrome, using split() on an empty string returns a one element array, the one element being an epmty string itself, which then causes the directory creation to fail. I modified it in order to correct the problem (there also some other not related changes, for my own purposes):

```
function createPath(fs, path, callback) {
    var dirs = path.split("/").reverse();
    var root = fs.root;

    var createDir = function(dir) {
        if (dir.trim()!="") {
            root.getDirectory(dir, {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            }, success, function(dir) {
                error("failed to create dir " + dir);
            });
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    };

    var success = function(entry) {
        root = entry;
        if (dirs.length > 0) {
            createDir(dirs.pop());
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    };

    createDir(dirs.pop());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(filesys) {
    filesys.root.getDirectory("story_repository", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dirEntry) {
        dirEntry.getDirectory("dir_name", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dirName) {
            dirName.getDirectory("img", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(imgDir) {
                console.log("img creation worked");
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("create img failed");
            });
            dirName.getDirectory("res", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(imgDir) {
                console.log("res creation worked");
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("create res failed");
            });
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("create dir_name failed");
        })
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("create story repository failed");
    });
}, function(error) {
    console.log("request file system failed");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
function recursiveGetFile(root, path, opts, success, fail) {
    function dir(entry) {
        var name = path.shift();
        if (path.length > 0)
            entry.getDirectory(name, opts, dir, fail);
        else
            entry.getFile(name, opts, success, fail);
    }
    path = path.split('/');
    dir(root);
}, fail);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple file manager for cordova-phoengap, with with you can do this and much more:

https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-simplefilemanagement

You can recursively create directories:

```
//CREATE A DIRECTORY RECURSIVELY as simple as:

new DirManager().create_r('folder_a/folder_b',Log('created successfully'));
```

Let me know if it helps